# Recovering text from a Thermal ESC/POS receipt byte buffer

Tags: linux, go, escpos

I'm trying to extract the text and numeric values from the byte stream using a Go application but I'm not having any luck.  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can save the data sent to the printer as a binary data file, you can use the tool I created in C# to analyze and output the contents. All you have to do is extract the text from it. [kunif/EscPosUtils](https://github.com/kunif/EscPosUtils)

Comment: @kunif - Thank you so much.  I will look at the kunif/EscPosUtils code base.  Can the kunif/EscPosUtils extract the text data as a shell command?

Comment: The tool itself has no such functionality. However, since the output result is text data that maintains a certain format, there may be many other tools for editing such text data. Also, the source code is open to the public, so you are free to modify it as you wish.